# settings.DATABASES is improperly configured” error django 3.1 while running inspect db

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to create models using inspect db command from postgres db. When i run the command,i am getting `raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. " django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`

Below is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {  },
'population_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'OPTIONS' : {
            'options': '-c search_path=dbo'
    },
    'NAME': 'SQLOPS_Population',
    'USER': 'devsqlservice',
    'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using the below command for inspect db

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database population_db population > model.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': { 
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'SQLOPS_Population',
    'USER': 'devsqlservice',
    'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 5432,
}
}
```

Comment: did you install psycopg2-binary?

Comment: Yes i have installed. I am getting inspect db running without any issue if default db is not empty. If it is empty i am getting error